# How to undo in turtle very fast?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am making a program that creates a spirograph. This is my code:

```
from turtle import *
from random import randint
speed(10000)
for i in range(20):
    col = randint(1, 5)
    if col == 1:
        pencolor("orange")
    elif col == 2:
        pencolor("blue")
    elif col == 3:
        pencolor("green")
    elif col == 4:
        pencolor("purple")
    elif col == 5:
        pencolor("dark blue")
    circle(50)
    left(20)

while undobufferentries():
    undo()
```

However, the last part of the program is the problemo. I want that part, the undo, to be very fast, as fast as the spiro was created. How to make undo very fast??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three times you say you want it "very fast", but you also say, "as fast as the spiro was created".  We can easily make it faster than the spiro was created, but just slightly more work to make it "as fast".

This problem points out the underbelly of the `undo()` mechanism.  To undo just one of your circles, involves a sequence of over 80 steps.  But, even that doesn't make it completely clear why it's *so* slow.  If we turn off screen updates, we can make it instantaneous.  But if that's acceptable, then you might as well replace `undo()` with `clear()`.

I rarely encourage folks to mess with `tracer()`, and even when I do, I usually write examples that do simple `tracer(False)` and `tracer(True)`, to avoid the numeric argument.  But this is the rare case where we want a specific numeric argument to `tracer()` to control the speed of the `undo()` graphics:

```
from turtle import *
from random import choice

COLORS = ["orange", "blue", "green", "purple", "dark blue"]

hideturtle()
speed('fastest')

for _ in range(20):
    pencolor(choice(COLORS))
    circle(50)
    left(20)

tracer(20)  # value unrelated to either 20 above
while undobufferentries() > 1:
    undo()  # undo everything but hideturtle()
tracer(1)

exitonclick()
```

On my system, the *undo* of the drawing is now the same speed as the *do*, but you may need to fine tune the argument to `tracer()` to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: Thanks @cdlane, but how to adjust the `tracer()` and how does this work?

Comment: @Programmer, you can read about `tracer()` in the turtle documentation.  The numeric argument represents how many screen updates to skip, that is in this case it's only doing one actual visual update once every 20 times they're requested.  When screen updates are skipped, graphics appear to happen faster.  By lowering the value, it will get faster at the expense of how much of the process you see.  At zero, you won't see the process at all and it will happen instantaneously.  Figuring out the proper number for you needs (speed vs. visual feedback) is what I mean by *tuning*.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach that doesn't involve `undo` is keeping a buffer (list) of drawing actions performed. When you're ready to "undo", loop over the buffer of actions, repeatedly re-drawing them on a freshly [reset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.reset) canvas. If you pop off the tail of the buffer on each rerender, you'll eventually reach an empty buffer, the origin state. This creates the illusion of gradually undoing the drawing operations.

The key here is disabling the rendering loop with `tracer(0)` and manually calling `turtle.update()` to draw each frame. `sleep()` sets the delay between frames, mostly for convenience; [`ontimer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.ontimer) is preferred.

Bear in mind that it takes more work to redraw everything per frame on the undo path which can impact performance.

```py
import turtle
from random import choice
from time import sleep

colors = (
    "orange",
    "blue",
    "green",
    "purple",
    "dark blue",
)

delay = 0.1
shapes = 20
step = 20
size = 50
turtle.tracer(0)
drawn = []

for _ in range(360 // step):
    turtle.pencolor(choice(colors))
    drawn.append(turtle.pencolor())
    turtle.circle(size)
    turtle.left(step)
    turtle.update()
    sleep(delay)

while drawn:
    drawn.pop()
    turtle.reset()

    for color in drawn:
        turtle.pencolor(color)
        turtle.circle(size)
        turtle.left(step)

    turtle.update()
    sleep(delay)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

Comment: This leaves a bit of a ghost image on my system.  Also, 10 is the highest value that `speed()` understands and it's probably better to use the 'slowest', 'slower' ... 'faster', 'fastest' alternatives.

Comment: @cdlane Both correct! I've updated to use a different technique.

Comment: Nice in that it should allow you consistent timing across machines rather than the 'tuning' mine requires.  (+1)  And visually smooth.  I still like getting the turtle to clean up after itself!  ;-)  I think `sleep(delay)` wouldn't be needed if turtle was more thoughtful about what effect `turtle(delay)` has on `turtle(update)`.  (Oh, and `shapes` isn't used.)